# Windows programm or tool to send key strokes to an specific browser tab

Tags: windows-10, browser, browser-tabs

I want to program myself a tool to send keystrokes or makros to a browser(tab) that is not focused.
That's something I'd like to have for some browser games. But I couldn't find anything on the internet that fits this use case and I don't know where to start program this by myself.

Is there a way to implement a program that can send keys to an (minimized) browser or a tab that is not displayed? Maybe some windows native suff? Or a browser extension? The problem should not be implementing this, but I don't know which way to go or where to start.

I'd like to hear some hints from you on how to get this working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### no, it is not possible,

...because operating systems with graphical interfaces can only "focus" on one thing at a time -- that being the active tab or window. just like it's impossible for a person to write a letter using paper that's at the bottom of a stack, a computer can't accept input to a process or window that's not active. the minor exceptions to this are things like scrolling through webpages even if they're not active, and hovering over buttons and whatnot -- but one may argue that's not necessarily "input".

### however, programs exist to make those browsers/tabs active,

such as [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), which is a personal favorite of mine. it's got an incredibly simplistic language to it meaning anyone can pick up on it and use it from the get-go, and there's no specific program you need to be able to code with it. you could use Notepad to make a perfectly running macro through it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found an interesting github repo: https://github.com/EasyAsABC123/Keyboard which is sending keys to background programs. I'll give it a try and inform you if it is working